# How to make app differentiate between Home Button press and Tab Change press

Tags: java, android

I have an App with tabs. It the Apps on Pause, I have some code which should work only when the user has pressed some other tab. I wrote that code but the problem is the  same thing is happening when I press the home button as well. Now how to make the App differentiate between the home button press and the tab change press. Please help.

Answer (score 0):

You have to `override` the `onkeypress` method. In that place your logic for home button and tab change...

Answer (score 0):

There is no formal way to be notified of a "HOME" key press. But there is a pretty simple work around to have your app distinguish between a "HOME" key press and any other action which would cause the Activity to stop.

For each class that need to perform some action on a "HOME" key press have them extend from an activity which contains this:

```
/**************************************** On Home **********************************/
  private boolean leaveCalled = false;
  @Override
  public void startActivity(Intent intent) {  
  leaveCalled= true;
  super.startActivity(intent);
  }


 @Override
 public void onBackPressed() {
 leaveCalled = true;
 super.onBackPressed();
 }

 @Override
 protected void onStop() {   
 super.onStop();
 // Home button pressed
 if(!leaveCalled) {
    // Do whatever you like.
  }

 leaveCalled = false;
 }
```

Now you have handle Home Click so i guess you can embed your working in it.. 
Hope this will help